# Viewing connected pptp clients IP

Tags: vpn, vps, ppp

I have a router connected locally to my office WAN, so router doesn't have a public IP address, just a local one. Now I don't have access to my Office WAN, so I created a VPN instead on my VPS so I can have a sort of PPP setup between the two and I will be able to connect to the router via my VPS.

So I basically setup a PPTP Client connection on my router to dial the VPN, which I thought will give my router a local address I can then connect with from VPS, but this isn't the case. list | grep ppp on my VPS shows my router still has the public ip address of my WAN instead. Why is this so? How can I find the local address assigned to my router (Mikrotik)